# Suckerfish drop-down submenu not aligned with main menu

Tags: css, menu, navigation, hover, suckerfish

I'm quite new with CSS so any help greatly appreciated. I'm currently using the Suckerfish script for my CSS menu, only because IE still exists. However, I can't get the second level menu to align directly under the first level -- not just IE, but Chrome and Safari as well.

I looked up solutions on this website, but I can't get them to work for my code...

Here's my CSS code (I'm sorry if it's messy):

```
#navbar {
 width: 900px;
 color: #a26868;
 font-size: 10px;
 padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
 float: left;
 background: #fff ; 
 }

#nav, #nav ul { 
    padding: 0px 15px 0px 15px;
    margin: 0;
    list-style: none;
    line-height: 18px;
}

#nav a {
    display: block;
    width: 140px;
}
#navbar li { 
   list-style: none;
   float: left; 
   padding: 0px 15px 0px 15px;
    display: block;
    width: 140px;
    text-align: center;
    height: 18px;
    background-image: url(line-nav.gif);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#navbar li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #a26868;
}
#navbar li ul {  
    list-style: none;
    color: #5e0505;
    background-image: url(line-nav.gif);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0.8);
    border-bottom: solid 1px #88c657;
    width: 140px;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    left:-999em;
}

#navbar li:hover ul, #navbar li.sfhover ul { 
    left: 0;
}
```

And this is the HTML code:

```
<ul id="navbar">
    <li><a href="#">ABOUT</a><ul>
        <li><a href="#">SUBITEM ONE</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">SUBITEM TWO</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">SUBITEM THREE</a></li></ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">SHOWCASE</a><ul>
        <li><a href="#">SUBITEM ONE</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">SUBITEM TWO</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">SUBITEM THREE</a></li></ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">PORTFOLIO</a><ul>
        <li><a href="#">SUBITEM ONE</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">SUBITEM TWO</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">SUBITEM THREE</a></li></ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">MEDIA</a><ul>
        <li><a href="#">SUBITEM ONE</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">SUBITEM TWO</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">SUBITEM THREE</a></li></ul>
    </li>
        <li><a href="#">CONTACT</a><ul>
        <li><a href="#">SUBITEM ONE</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">SUBITEM TWO</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">SUBITEM THREE</a></li></ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Please, any help greatly appreciated. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

try this one,

```
#navbar li:hover ul, #navbar li.sfhover ul { 
    left:-50px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Yt66E/

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I preferred not to adjust the left spacing with the -50px as it seems less flexible.

Answer (score 0):

your sub menu `ul` has padding and `li` too so you need to remove these paddings like this:

edit this **CSS**:

```
#navbar li:hover ul, #navbar li.sfhover ul { 
    left: 0;
    padding:0;  /*  added  */
}
```

and add this **CSS**:

```
#navbar li li{
    padding:0;
}
```

[**jsFiddle is here**](http://jsfiddle.net/mohsen4887/73rBy/)

Comment: Thank you very much, this worked better than the first answer.